# Trying to setup mimik's back-end services on AWS Ec2 instance

Tags: edgesdk

Here are a few clarifications we need from you :

1. Not able to find back-end service (mDS, mSS) components on GitHub. Could you let us know the path and the implementation steps? We are trying to deploy mimik's back-end components on the EC2 instance and try to configure/access the micro service deployed on the local laptop from another device.
2. How can we deploy microservices written in other languages like java, python etc. we can see support for microservices written in Java Script( Node JS) only.

Answer (score 1):

1. mDS and mSS are core mimik backend services and are not publicly available on any website. The capabilities/functionalities of mSS and mDS are provided within edgeEngine during runtime on supported platforms. You can learn about these concepts and develop your own solutions in tandem with edgeEngine and various backend microservices on our developer portal below:  https://developer.mimik.com/products/

1.1. You can run edgeEngine on any of our supported platforms and deploy any of our publicly available local microservices as a way of learning how to develop, deploy and work with edge-microservice.

2. The agent program on any platform can be developed by any desired programming language; however, for exposing a restful API at the edge to provide any specific function or for orchestration purpose, you need to develop them using JavaScript. In this way you can re-use the microservice and deploy them dynamically on all platforms with different operating systems. This means we only support the deployment of microservices written in JavaScript on to edegEngine environment

If you are trying to develop your own commercial solution please contact mimik support team directly at support@mimik.com.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above response by Maz Mandi, please note that your application on top of edgeEngine (application and microservices) will communicate with your application back-end directly vs. going through mimik global functions such as mDS and mSS.